# Counting sentences *not* lines of a text file

Tags: matlab

For an assignment I need to find the number of sentences of a text file (not the lines). That means at the end of string I will have '.' or '!' or '?'. After struggling a lot I wrote a code, which is giving an error. I do not see any mistake though. If anyone can help me, that will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code

```
fh1 = fopen(nameEssay); %nameEssay is a string of the name of the file with .txt
line1 = fgetl(fh1);
```

% line1 gives the title of the essay. that is not counted as a sentence

```
essay = [];
line = ' ';
while ischar(line)
    line =fgetl(fh1);
    essay = [essay line];
    %creates a long string of the whole essay
end

sentenceCount=0;
allScore = [ ];



[sentence essay] = strtok(essay, '.?!');
 while ~isempty(sentence)
    sentenceCount = sentenceCount + 1;
    sentence = [sentence essay(1)];

    essay= essay(3:end); %(1st character is a punctuation. 2nd is a space.)
    while ~isempty(essay)
        [sentence essay] = strtok(essay, '.?!');
    end

end
fclose(fh1);
```

Comment: What error and which line?

Comment: Rather than `strtok`, you should take a look at [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html), then you can just count the length of the cell matrix it returns.

Comment: after counting two sentences it gives error here
"sentence = [sentence essay(1)]" says numel(essay)=0. 
However, I do not see the reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) handles this nicely:

```
>> essay = 'First sentence. Second one? Third! Last one.'
essay =
First sentence. Second one? Third! Last one.
>> sentences = regexp(essay,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')
sentences = 
    'First sentence.'    'Second one?'    'Third!'    'Last one.'
```

In the pattern `'\S.*?[\.\!\?]'`, the `\S` says a sentence starts with a non-whitespace character, the `.*?` matches any number of characters (non-greedily), until a punctuation marking the end of a sentence (`[\.\!\?]`) is encountered.

Comment: It looks like a nice command. However, we are not taught that yet! Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

If you count number of senteces, based on  '.' or '!' or '?', you can just calculate the number of these characters in essey. Thus, if essay is array containing characters you can do:

```
essay = 'Some sentece. Sentec 2! Sentece 3? Sentece 4.';


% count number of  '.' or '!' or '?' in essey.
sum(essay == abs('.')) 
sum(essay == abs('?'))
sum(essay == abs('!'))

% gives, 2, 1, 1. Thus there are 4 sentences in the example.
```

If you want senteces, you can use [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) as Dan suggested, e.g.

```
[C, matches] = strsplit(essay,{'.','?', '!'}, 'CollapseDelimiters',true)

% gives
C = 

    'Some sentece'    ' Sentec 2'    ' Sentece 3'    ' Sentece 4'    ''


matches = 

    '.'    '!'    '?'    '.'
```

And calculate the number of elements in matches. For the example last element is empty. It can be filtered out easly.

Comment: yup...that's true. However, I need the actual sentence also, for another task of the entire function! Therefore, I need both. Sorry. I should have mentioned that. And thanks!

Comment: @user3226108 I amended the anwser

Comment: I think strsplit( ) is a new command. I am using 2011 version. There is no such command. Even if I had, it would be useful for this task ( as I understand). Because, it eliminates the punctuation from sentence. I need a complete sentence. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @user3226108 Check chappjc anwser. It should be it.